Bijection between relation and matrix

The number of $3\times3$ non singular matrices with four entries as 1 and all other entries as 0, is [(JEE Main 2010)]

Inspired by this question (on representing relations using matrices), I tried converting it into the language of relations:

Set A and Set B have three elements each. Count the number of relations from $A$ to $B$ such that

Every element in A is associated with at least one element in B.
Every element in B is associated with at least one element in A.
Cardinality of the relation when represented as a set of ordered pairs is exactly four.


Represent the relation using a $3\times3$ matrix.

Every element in A is associated with at least one element in B: Every row has a 1.
Every element in B is associated with at least one element in A: Every column has a 1.

Combining the above two: Each column and row has at lesat one 1 (three 1's).

Cardinality of the relationship is 4: We have an extra 1 to place among the remaining six positions.

Hence the second problem reduces to the first. Is this correct?
